# Bouncy Castle PBKDF2WithHmacSHA3-256 implementation

Tags: java, bouncycastle

I am trying to encrypt the password using the PBKDF2WithHmacSHA3-256. Based on the bouncycastle sample, I have the following sample
JAVA Code

The output from the Java code and Node JS seems to be different.

```
    public static void main (String args[]) {
        
        String saltVal = "a5dcea8d0bba2f1fcfa5824085bf06e65fa1255484dafd499984323672b71fee";
        String passwordToHash = "password";
        int iterations = 10000;
        
        try {
            
            PKCS5S2ParametersGenerator generator = new PKCS5S2ParametersGenerator((new SHA3Digest(256)));
            generator.init(passwordToHash.getBytes("UTF-8"),
                    saltVal.getBytes(),
                    iterations);

            byte[] derivedKey = ((KeyParameter)generator.generateDerivedParameters(32 * 8)).getKey();    
            
            
            BigInteger bi = new BigInteger(1, derivedKey);
            System.out.println(String.format("%0" + (derivedKey.length << 1) + "x", bi));

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Node JS

```
const crypto = require("crypto");

const iteration = 10000;
const length = 32;
const digest = "sha3-256";
const sharedSecret = "a5dcea8d0bba2f1fcfa5824085bf06e65fa1255484dafd499984323672b71fee"; 
const valuesToHash = ["password"];

const hashFn = (value, salt) => {
    const saltBuf = Buffer.from(salt, "hex")
    const key = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(value, saltBuf, iteration, length, digest);
    return key.toString("hex");
}

for (const value of valuesToHash) {
    console.log(`>>> ${value}: ${hashFn(value, sharedSecret)}`);
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: The posted code implements PBKDF2/HMAC with SHA3-256. SHA1 is used by default, e.g. if you do not specify a digest in the constructor. The [documentation](https://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/docs1.5on/org/bouncycastle/crypto/generators/PKCS5S2ParametersGenerator.html) is not accurate here or has not been updated properly.

Comment: Thanks @Topaco 

I am comparing the output with nodejs, both seem to be different, 
`
const hashFn = (value, salt) => {
 const saltBuf = Buffer.from(salt, "hex")
 const key = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(value, saltBuf, PBKDF2_HASH_ITERATIONS, PBKDF2_KEY_LENGTH, PBKDF2_DIGEST_ALGORITHM);
 return key.toString("hex");
}
`
The output for the java and the nodejs seems to be different, although the input values are the same.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this! Probably you use different input parameters, wrong encodings or similar. Post the _complete_ codes including _all test data_ so that a repro is possible. And, please do not post this in a comment, but edit your question and append the new code with the test data to the end.

Comment: @Topaco , Updated the question with the code. Thanks!

Comment: In Java you treat the salt as characters, but in nodejs as hex; this gives a different value, and thus different result. The Java default charset varies by environment, which you didn't state, but since your string is all ASCII it is the same in any plausible default charset, and could be encoded as any of `ascii`, `latin1` aka `binary`, or `utf8` in nodejs, the last being the default and thus omittable.

Comment: Alternatively, if you want to hex decode the salt in the Java code, BouncyCastle also supports this with `org.bouncycastle.util.encoders.Hex` and you simply have to replace `saltVal.getBytes()` with `Hex.decode(saltVal)`. In any case, hex encoding is easier with `Hex.toHexString(derivedKey)` (without `BigInteger` detour). From Java 17 on there is a built in support for hex encoding.

Comment: _"encrypt the password using the PBKDF2WithHmacSHA3-256"_. PBKDF2WithHmacSHA3-256 is not encryption, it is a password hash (or "password-based key derivation function").

Answer (score 0):

This is the updated code. The salt and iterations are defined outside.

```
    private static String encodePassword (String password) 
    {
        String returnVal = "";
        
        try {
            
            PKCS5S2ParametersGenerator generator = new PKCS5S2ParametersGenerator((new SHA3Digest(256)));
            generator.init(password.getBytes("UTF-8"),
                    Hex.decode(saltVal),
                    iterations);

            byte[] derivedKey = ((KeyParameter)generator.generateDerivedParameters(32 * 8)).getKey();    
            returnVal = Hex.toHexString(derivedKey);
            
            System.out.println(">>> " + password + " : " + returnVal);

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        return returnVal;
    }
```

Comment: Is this intended as an answer? If so, please explain how this solves the problem. If this is intended as an update to your question, then update your question by editing the question.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).